# what is the equivalent of ctrl+h (find and replace) in cmd command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, file-management, text-editing, command-line-arguments

I need instructions specific to the command line (Windows 10) to modify a text file, by replacing a word with another word I thought of the for loop but I did not find a command to modify a file text?

j'ai besoin des instruction propre a la ligne de commande(Windows 10) pour modifier un fichier texte, en remplaçant un mot par un autre mot j'ai penser a la boucle for mais j'ai pas trouver une commande pour modifier un fichier texte?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943606/replacing-a-certain-word-in-the-text-using-batch-scripting

Comment: For those who think the title doesn't match the question: Ctrl-H is the shortcut for  Search/Replace in many text-editors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285047/how-replace-a-word-in-a-text-file-using-a-bat-file

Comment: @Gantendo It is a duplicate for all those other questions. (I was looking for them too, but you were faster.)

Comment: @Tonny Yeah, feel free to mark it as a duplicate. Originally the question was in French so the (somewhat clunky) translation is thanks to Google Translate.

Comment: @Gantendo My French isn't stellar, but that translation looks good enough :-)

Comment: @Gantendo Can't VTC as duplicate because those other questions are on Stackoverflow. Need a dupe on Superuser.